# python How to iterate over two files and grep only one line before the match

Tags: python

This is `names.txt`:

```
David
Mary
Rose
Saeed
```

This is `emails.txt`:

```
  - address1@gmail.com
  - Mary
  - address2@gmail.com
  - Rose
  - address3@hotmail.com
  - David
  - address4@yahoo.com
  - Saeed
  - address5@gmail.com
  - Jones
```

In `emails.txt` there are more emails than `names.txt`.

I want to grep each name in `names.txt` and `grep` that name but only one line before that.

For example, to `grep` the name `David` and find its email `address3@hotmail.com`.

This is my python code up to now (which only prints the first line of `names.txt`:

```
import re

with open('names.txt', 'r') as file:
    with open('emails.txt', 'r') as emails:
        for name in file:
            for email in emails:
                if re.search(name, email):
                    print(email)
```

I'll update the question when I find something new to get closer to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import re

with open('names.txt', 'r') as names_file:
    with open('emails.txt', 'r') as emails_file:
        names = names_file.readlines()
        emails = emails_file.readlines()

        for name in names:
            name = name.strip()
            for i, email in enumerate(emails):
                email = re.sub('-', '', email)
                if re.search(name, email):
                    prev_email = emails[i-1].strip()
                    prev_email = re.sub('-', '', prev_email)
                    print(f"Name: {name}, Email: {prev_email}")
                    break
```

Result

```
Name: David, Email:  address3@hotmail.com
Name: Mary, Email:  address1@gmail.com
Name: Rose, Email:  address2@gmail.com
Name: Saeed, Email:  address4@yahoo.com
```

Comment: One line's output is: `Name: David, Email: - address3@hotmail.com` and there is a `-` in the output of email. Can you edit the code to remove the dash and space before email address? Sample output could be like `Name: David, Email: address3@hotmail.com`.

Comment: ok updated, just add `re.sub('-', '')`

Comment: If this solved your issue, please accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's solved, but please wait a couple of hours if there are any other answers. That's very kind of you answered my question, buddy.

Comment: @Saeed, Do not be rude. If this answer resolved your question you should mark it as accepted. Personally I don't think this answer is anywhere close to optimal but SO is not a free code writing service. If you want a better solution my rate is $50/hour with a two hour minimum.

Comment: @KurtisRader I don't intend that, because another user in SO told me not to choose best answer fast so that other users share their ideas too. That's the only reason he told me a couple of times. But, sure I'll choose this as best.